# COUNT non-null values for multiple columns are the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to count non-null values for three columns. However, the same COUNT is returned for each of the three columns despite having differing number of non-null values. I'm not sure why this is the case (do I need to recast the column data type? wrong SQL clause?). Below is what I've tried and the results.

*EDIT: replaced images with text. made shorter aliases.*

```
SELECT  CAST(users.install_ts AS Date) AS inst_date, 
        COUNT(users.install_ts) AS total_inst, 
        COUNT(users.firstlogin_ts) AS total_first_logins,
        COUNT(users.firstpurchase_ts) AS conv_cust,
        SUM(CASE WHEN users.firstpurchase_ts IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conv_cust
FROM users
GROUP BY CAST(users.install_ts AS Date)

inst_date   total_inst  total_first_logins  conv_cust  conv_cust  
----------  ----------  ------------------  ---------  ---------  
2015-01-01  17191       17191               17191      0          
2015-01-02  41038       41038               41038      0          
2015-01-03  41176       41176               41176      0          
2015-01-04  41072       41072               41072      0          
2015-01-05  41115       41115               41115      0          
2015-01-06  8417        8417                8417       0          
2015-05-16  9991        9991                9991       0
```

Here is the `users` table:

```
uid     device_id   install_ts           firstlogin_ts        firstpurchase_ts     
------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  -------------------  
121045  GalaxyS3    2015-01-01 14:00:01  2015-01-01 14:00:01  (null)               
121046  GalaxyS1    2015-01-01 14:00:03  2015-01-01 14:00:07  2015-01-02 06:00:07  
121047  iPhone3     2015-01-01 14:00:03  2015-01-01 14:00:03  (null)               
121048  GalaxyS1    2015-01-01 14:00:04  (null)               (null)               
121049  iPhone5     2015-01-01 14:00:07  2015-01-01 14:00:08  (null)               
121050  iPad4       2015-01-01 14:00:07  2015-01-01 14:00:09  (null)               
121051  iPhone4s    2015-01-01 14:00:11  (null)               (null)               
121052  iPhone4s    2015-01-01 14:00:13  (null)               (null)               
121053  GalaxyTab3  2015-01-01 14:00:16  (null)               (null)               
121054  iPhone4     2015-01-01 14:00:19  2015-01-01 14:00:22  (null)               
121055  iPad1       2015-01-01 14:00:22  2015-01-01 14:00:26  (null)               
121056  iPad2       2015-01-01 14:00:26  2015-01-01 14:00:29  (null)               
121057  GalaxyTab2  2015-01-01 14:00:30  2015-01-01 14:00:31  (null)               
121058  iPhone5s    2015-01-01 14:00:34  2015-01-01 14:00:38  (null)               
121059  GalaxyS5    2015-01-01 14:00:34  (null)               (null)               
121060  GalaxyS5    2015-01-01 14:00:34  2015-01-01 14:00:38  (null)               
121061  GalaxyS5    2015-01-01 14:00:37  (null)               (null)               
121062  iPhone3     2015-01-01 14:00:39  (null)               (null)
```

Description of the table:

```
DESCRIBE users
Field             Type         Null  Key  Default              Extra                        
----------------  -----------  ----  ---  -------------------  ---------------------------  
uid               int(11)      YES   MUL  (null)                                            
device_id         varchar(64)  YES        (null)                                            
install_ts        timestamp    NO         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
firstlogin_ts     timestamp    NO         0000-00-00 00:00:00                               
firstpurchase_ts  timestamp    NO         0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

*EDIT: Doing them one at a time gives the same results. So maybe it is a grouping problem. If that's the case, how do I go about achieving my intended results?*

One at a time:

```
SELECT  COUNT(users.firstlogin_ts) AS total_first_logins
FROM users
GROUP BY CAST(users.install_ts AS Date)

total_first_logins
17191  
41038  
41176  
41072  
41115  
8417   
9991
```

Another column:

```
SELECT COUNT(users.install_ts) AS total_inst
FROM users
GROUP BY CAST(users.install_ts AS Date)

total_inst
17191  
41038  
41176  
41072  
41115  
8417   
9991
```

Comment: sure. I think I've done what you've asked. thanks.

Comment: You grouping seems like it could cause some issues; at very least you should be selecting the cast instead of a (effectively random) install_ts within the cast's value range. _I still wouldn't think it would cause your count values problem though._

Comment: Is that the exact query you used, or are you `join`ing to `logins` and/or `revenue` in any way?

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, that is the exact query I used.

Comment: Might be a bug. What if you run only one of the counts?

Comment: Maybe table needs repaired.

Comment: Try `sum(case when <col> is not null then 1 end)` just to see if that changes anything.

Comment: If the datatype of `firstlogin_ts` is actually a Timestamp and not a VarChar with a literal value of `(null)` it's a wrong result. What is returned when you do a `select * from users where firstlogin_ts is null`?

Comment: As others pointed out, there must be some problem with the database. Check out this fiddle, it works as you'd expect it to: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e1a2/1 - can you possibly replicate your issue in this example fiddle?

Comment: @dnoeth I ran your code and got: [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.083 secs]  Empty result set fetched. This seems like a promising hint: the nulls aren't even detected. How would I account for this in my query though? Cast it as a different data type?

Comment: Check the datatype if it's really a timestamp and not a VarChar. For VarChars this should work: `COUNT(NULLIF(firstlogin_ts, '(null)'))`. But then you should fix your data model, of course :-)

Comment: @jirka Thanks for sharing that site and re-creating a portion of my DB. It's very useful. The results there are what I expected to see. I fiddled around but can't replicate the issue. I'm connecting to a remote DB for which I am unable to modify. I can only run queries.

Comment: @dnoeth I posted a DESCRIBE statement above. It is timestamp. SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(firstlogin_ts, '(null)')) FROM users returns all rows in the table.

Comment: @shawnt00 The code you shared just returns all rows in the table.

Comment: A lot of people here assume that `(null)` in the question means VARCHAR-typed string "(null)". Since this is supposed to be TIMESTAMP-typed column, I suppose it's really NULL value, right?

Comment: If your columns aren't nullable then where are those values coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing there might be a display issue at the root of your problem. The data you present shows `(null)`, but the table description indicates the fields are not nullable in the first place. However, the fields default to '0000-00-00 00:00:00', which is not quite a valid value for the type, but allowed (it's weird). Some APIs convert such values to null, even though they are not actually NULL in the database. Try this instead:

```
SELECT  CAST(users.install_ts AS Date) AS inst_date, 
        COUNT(1) AS total_inst, 
        COUNT(NULLIF(users.firstlogin_ts, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')) AS total_first_logins,
        COUNT(NULLIF(users.firstpurchase_ts, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')) AS conv_cust
FROM users
GROUP BY CAST(users.install_ts AS Date)
```

`NULLIF` will convert such values to true `NULL` values.

Comment: This solved the problem! Thanks for the helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this as specified here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64927/count-null-and-not-null-values-in-a-column

```
SELECT  CAST(users.install_ts AS Date) AS inst_date, 
        COUNT(!ISNULL(users.install_ts)) AS total_inst, 
        COUNT(!ISNULL(users.firstlogin_ts)) AS total_first_logins,
        COUNT(!ISNULL(users.firstpurchase_ts)) AS conv_cust,
        SUM(!ISNULL(users.firstpurchase_ts)) AS conv_cust
FROM users
GROUP BY CAST(users.install_ts AS Date)
```

Comment: I ran that query and I get the same results. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the columns are coded as "timestamp"?